# как связать headerView c tableview в детальной сцене?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, navigationbar

Столкнулся с проблемой: делаю детальную сцену `headerView` и `tableviewCell`, ячейка у меня `xib`. При открытии детальной сцене и скроллинге, Header с картинкой имеет постоянное положение, а текст пролистывается и заходит под него. Я сделал `navigator bar` прозрачным `transparent`. Может, это из за этого?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSoccerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var detailSoccer: Soccer!

    var selectedSoccer = [Soccer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 288
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerHeaderView",bundle:Bundle.main), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "SoccerHeaderView")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "soccerCell")

        tableView.reloadData()
        loadMatchSoccer()
           //Header            
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let soccerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soccerCell", for: indexPath) as! SoccerTableViewCell

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Аналитика и обзор матча:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.textSoccer
        case 1:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Прогноз на матч:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.detailPrognozS
        default:
            break
        }

     return soccerCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SoccerHeaderView") as! SoccerHeaderView

        header.soccerName.text = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        return header
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func loadMatchSoccer() {

        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>
        query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.detailTitleS)
        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.selectedSoccer = objects!

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: UItableView style у Вас plain?

Comment: да , plain стоит...Но я пробовал группу ставить че то не то выходит!